# Set Publish Date for CMS Pages in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I would like my homepage to change daily. Is it possible to set dates for the homepage of magento to change daily? I would like a different homepage to be published each day of the week. Is this possible? I am using Community edition 1.7

Answer (score 1):

Magento OOB does not have such a feature.

But it's definitely possible, of course. Check http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ to see whether such extension already exists. Or just develop your own custom extension.